# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$sql' (T_VARIABLE) の構文エラーが発生してしまう

Tags: php

この文がsyntaxエラーになる理由がわかりません。

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO drink_info_table(drink_id, drink_name, price, stock, created_at, updated_at, status) VALUES(\''.$drink_id.'\',\''.$new_name.'\',\''.$new_price.'\',\''.$new_stock.'\',\''.$new_time.'\',\''.$new_time.'\',\''.$new_status.'\')';
```

ちなみに画面を開いたらこのようなエラーになります。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

お手数をおかけしますがご確認のほどよろしくお願いいたします。

**ソースコード**

```
<?php
require_once('../../include/conf/const.php');
require_once('../../htdocs/mvc/tool.php');


function get_db_connect() {
 
if (!$link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWD, DB_NAME)) {
        die('error: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    mysqli_set_charset($link, DB_CHARACTER_SET);
    return $link;
}

function close_db_connect($link) {

    mysqli_close($link);
}

function insert_drink($link) {
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] !== 'POST') {
    return;
}
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && $_POST['sql_kind'] === 'insert') {
        
        if (isset($_POST['new_name']) === TRUE) {
            
            $new_name = $_POST['new_name'];
            
                
        }
        
        if (isset($_POST['new_price']) === TRUE) {
        
            $new_price = $_POST['new_price'];
            
        }
        
        if (isset($_POST['new_stock']) === TRUE) {
            
            $new_stock = $_POST['new_stock'];
            
            
        }
        
        if (isset($_POST['new_status']) === TRUE) {
        if ((int) $_POST['new_status'] === 0 || (int) $_POST['new_status'] === 1) {
             $new_status = (int) $_POST['new_status'];
        }
            
        }

            $new_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
　　　　　　
            
            $sql = 'INSERT INTO drink_info_table(drink_id, drink_name, price, stock, created_at, updated_at, status) VALUES(\''.$drink_id.'\',\''.$new_name.'\',\''.$new_price.'\',\''.$new_stock.'\',\''.$new_time.'\',\''.$new_time.'\',\''.$new_status.'\')';

            if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql) === TRUE) {

                $drink_id = mysqli_insert_id($link);
            } else {
                $err_msg[] = 'drink_info_tableへのデータの登録に失敗しました';
                
                
            }
                $complete_msg[] = '追加登録完了!';
                
            }
}

        
function update_drink($link) {
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && $_POST['sql_kind'] === 'update') {

        if (isset($_POST['update_stock']) === TRUE) {
            
                $update_stock = (int)($_POST['update_stock']);

                $update_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

                $update_id = $_POST['drink_id'];

                $sql = 'UPDATE drink_info_table SET stock = ' . $update_stock . ', updated_at = \'' . $update_time . '\' WHERE drink_id = ' . $update_id;

                if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql) === TRUE) {
                    $complete_msg[] = '在庫数更新完了!';
                } else {
                    $err_msg[] = '在庫数の更新に失敗しました';
                    
                }
            }
        }
        return $complete_msg;
}
// function change_drink() {
//     if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && $_POST['sql_kind'] === 'change') {

//         if (isset($_POST['change_status']) === TRUE) {
//             if ((int) $_POST['change_status'] === 0 || (int) $_POST['change_status'] === 1) {
//                 $change_id = $_POST['drink_id'];
//                 $change_status = (int) $_POST['change_status'];

//                 $change_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

//                 $sql = 'UPDATE drink_info_table SET updated_at = \'' . $change_time . '\', status = ' . $change_status . ' WHERE drink_id = ' . $change_id;


//                 if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql) === TRUE) {
//                     $complete_msg[] = 'ステータス変更完了!';
                    
//                 } else {
//                     $err_msg[] = 'ステータスの変更に失敗しました';
//                 }
//             } else {
//                 $err_msg[] = 'ステータスは公開か非公開を選択してください';
//             }
//         }
//     }

//     if (count($err_msg) === 0) {
        
//         mysqli_commit($link);
//     } else {
        
//         mysqli_rollback($link);
//     }

//     $sql = 'SELECT drink_info_table.drink_id, drink_info_table.drink_name, drink_info_table.price, stock_table.stock, drink_info_table.status, FROM drink_info_table LEFT JOIN stock_table ON drink_info_table.drink_id = stock_table.drink_id';
    
//     if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {

//         while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
//             $data[] = $row;
//         }
//     } else {
//         $err_msg[] = 'データの抽出に失敗しました';
//     }
// }



function do_sql($link) {
    $sql = 'SELECT drink_info_table.drink_id, drink_info_table.drink_name, drink_info_table.price, drink_info_table.stock, drink_info_table.status
    FROM drink_info_table';
    $data = [];
    if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
    } else {
        $err_msg[] = 'データの抽出に失敗しました';
    }
    return $data;
}

// function id_check() {
//     if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

//         $purchase_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

//         if (isset($_POST['drink_id']) === TRUE) {

//             switch (TRUE) {
//                 case ($_POST['drink_id'] === ''):
//                     $err_msg[] = 'index.phpからdrink_idを受信できませんでした';
//                     break;
//                 case ($_POST['drink_id'] === NULL):
//                     $err_msg[] = 'index.phpからdrink_idを受信できませんでした';
//                     break;
//                 default:
//                     $drink_id = (int) $_POST['drink_id'];
//                     break;
//             }
//         } else {
//             $err_msg[] = '商品を選択してください';
//         }

//         if (isset($_POST['money']) === TRUE) {

//             switch (TRUE) {
//                 case ($_POST['money'] === ''):
//                     $err_msg[] = '金額を入力してください';
                    
//                     break;
//                 case ($_POST['money'] === NULL):
//                     $err_msg[] = 'index.phpからmoneyを受信できませんでした';
                    
//                     break;
//                 case (preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/', cut($_POST['money'])) !== 1):
//                     $err_msg[] = '金額は0以上の半角整数を入力してください';
                    
//                     break;
//                 default:
//                     $money = (int) cut($_POST['money']);
//                     break;
//             }
//         }

//         if (count($err_msg) === 0) {

//             $sql = 'SELECT drink_info_table.drink_name, drink_info_table.price,  drink_info_table.status, stock_table.stock
//             FROM drink_info_table
//             JOIN stock_table
//             ON drink_info_table.drink_id = stock_table.drink_id
//             WHERE drink_info_table.drink_id = ' . $drink_id;

//             if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {

//                 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
//                     $data[] = $row;
//                 }
//             } else {
//                 $err_msg[] = '情報の取得に失敗しました';
//             }

//             foreach ($data as $info) {

//                 $drink_name = $info['drink_name'];
//                 $price = (int) $info['price'];
//                 $stock = (int) $info['stock'];
//                 $status = (int) $info['status'];

//                 $remaining_stock = $stock - 1;
//                 $return = $money - $price;
//             }

//             switch (TRUE) {
//                 case ($return < 0):
//                     $err_msg[] = 'お金が足りません';
                    
//                     break;
//                 case ($remaining_stock < 0):
//                     $err_msg[] = 'この商品は品切れです';
                    
//                     break;
//                 case ($status === 0):
//                     $err_msg[] = 'この商品は選択できません';
                    
//                     break;
//             }

//             $sql = 'UPDATE stock_table SET stock = ' . $remaining_stock . ', updated_at = \'' . $purchase_time . '\' WHERE drink_id = ' . $drink_id;

//             if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {

//                 $sql = 'INSERT INTO drink_history_table(drink_id, purchased_at) VALUES (' . $drink_id . ', \'' . $purchase_time . '\')';

//                 if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql) !== TRUE) {
//                     $err_msg[] = 'drink_history_tableへの追加に失敗しました';
                    
//                 }
//             } else {
//                 $err_msg[] = 'stock_tableの更新に失敗しました';
//         }
        
//     }
// }

// function html_enc($text){ 
// return htmlspecialchars($text, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
// }
// }

function validation_check($link) {
   $err_msg = [];
   if (!isset($_POST['new_name']) || (isset($_POST['new_name']) && $_POST['new_name'] === ""))  {
     $err_msg[] = '商品名を入力してください。';
    }
    
    if (!isset($_POST['new_price']) || (isset($_POST['new_price']) && $_POST['new_price'] === "")) {
     $err_msg[] = '値段を入力してください';
    } else if(preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/',($_POST['new_price'])) !== 1) {
     $err_msg[] = '値段は0以上の半角整数を入力してください';
    }
    
    if (!isset($_POST['new_stock']) || (isset($_POST['new_stock']) && $_POST['new_stock'] === "")) {
     $err_msg[] = '在庫を入力してください';
    } else if(preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/',($_POST['new_stock'])) !== 1) {
     $err_msg[] = '在庫は0以上の半角整数を入力してください';
    }
    
    if ((int) $_POST['new_status'] === 2) {
     $err_msg[] = 'ステータスは公開か非公開を選択してください'; 
    }
    if (!empty($_POST["update_stock"])) {
    if (preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/',($_POST['update_stock'])) !== 1) {
    } else {
     $err_msg[] = '0以上の半角整数を入力してください';
}

}
     return $err_msg;
}
```

Comment: `$new_time = ...` の行と `$sql = ...` の間に `U+3000`(IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE, 俗に言う「全角文字」)が入っています。

Comment: 今確認したら直せました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: コメント欄は回答するものではないです

Comment: @metropolis [コメントで解決した質問には、回答を投稿してほしい](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2645) も参照してください。